# Struts - In which jar file all the .tld files located

Tags: java, struts2, struts, struts-html

I am developing a `Struts` based web application. I am new to `Struts`. I want to use `struts-html.tld taglib`, provided by struts, in my jsp pages.

When I searched on net, I came to know that prior to `Struts 1.2.9`, we need to locate the `.tld` files manually.

But now these `.tld`  files are packed in .jar files and we need to just use those jar files as any other jar file in our project.

Q1. So my question is in Which jar file these `.tld` files are located. I came to know from a `Javaranch` answer that these `.tld` files are packed into `struts-taglib.jar` file. I downloaded the full struts libraries but didn't find that jar file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not clear which version of Struts you're using but the TLD you are referring to is a Struts 1 TLD.

In Struts 1.3.10, it is bundled in `struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar/META-INF/tld/struts-html.tld` which is distributed in [`struts-1.3.10-lib.zip`](http://apache.multidist.com/struts/library/struts-1.3.10-lib.zip). 
In Struts 1.2.9, you'll find it in the root of [`struts-1.2.9-lib.zip`](http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/library/struts-1.2.9-lib.zip).

Just in case, note that Struts 2 uses a completely different tag library than Struts 1 and there is only one taglib instead of several. The corresponding TLD is located in `struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar/META-INF/struts-tags.tld`.

Comment: I am using `struts 2.1.8.1`. I have dropped `struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar` in `\WEB-INF\lib` directory. After that I have used `<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="/struts-tags">` in one of my jsp pages in which I want to use `<html:form>` tags provided by struts. But I got one exception which you could see at question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395364/struts-exception-the-struts-dispatcher-cannot-be-found

Comment: Check my answer to that question @Yatendra Goel

Answer (score 2):

`struts2-core-2.2.1.1.jar`  will contain the TLD file at the following location 
`struts2-core-2.2.1.1.jar/META-INF/struts-tags.tld`

Answer (score 0):

I looked in one of our projects using Struts.  I can see this tld file: `struts2-core-j4-2.0.11.jar\META-INF\struts-tags.tld`

Note you can search through Jar files using Windows search.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878769/how-to-search-jar-files-using-windows-search) if you're having issues searching.

Comment: Struts 2 tags are not compatible on Struts 1 tags. Actually Struts 2 is from the `WebWork 2` project. It won't work on Struts 1.

Answer (score 0):

Download the **Full Distribution** of [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts1310) and find the **struts-blank.war** in the archive. Extract the struts-blank.war and under the `WEB-INF` folder, copy all the `.tld` files into your `WEB-INF` folder.