# Struts - Alternative of <html:errors /> to display error messages in Jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Struts - Alternative of `<html:errors />` to display error messages in Jsp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By setting the attribute `message="false"` on the `<html:messages />` tag, it gets all errors stored on `ActionMessages` list if `saveErrors` was called.

```
<logic:messagesPresent message="false">
                        <html:messages id="aMsg" message="false">
                            <logic:present name="aMsg">
                                <!-- Error -->
                                <div class="error">
                                    <bean:write name="aMsg" filter="false" />
                                </div>
                            </logic:present>
                        </html:messages>
                    </logic:messagesPresent>
```

The `<html:messages id="aMsg" message="false">` display messages stored on `saveErrors` while `<html:messages id="aMsg" message="true">` display messages stored on `saveMessages`. There is no more `ActionErrors` object, just `ActionMessages`. The 'saveErrors' and 'saveMessages' method seperates the errors and messages respectively.

Comment: Actually I wanted to use <html:errors /> for displaying errors but I couldn't find struts-html.tld file that's why I moved to other alternative approaches... Could you please tell me the answer of the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388133/struts-in-which-jar-file-all-the-tld-files-located

Comment: <html:errors /> has been removed on the newer versions of Struts. It hasn't been removed on the TLD's since Struts have long removed their TLD's from the Struts set. They just keeping it for backward compatibility purposes. Rather use JSTL has it's compatible to be used with Struts.